# Trying to get order total to show in custom reports for Woocommerce

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a plugin Im developing that adds some custom reports to the Woocommerce reports section in Wordpress.  Our check out page has two custom fields where users have to answer before checking out.  These custom fields on the check out are things like "How did you find us?" with a few options and one for "Reason for purchase?" with a few options.

The plugin will show how many times each option was used specified by a date range.  I have all of that working no problem.  Now I want to add to the report by how much revenue was generated for each option.

This will show me the meta_value (reason for purchase) and how many times it was used:

```
$sql = "SELECT *,

                count(distinct order_id) AS 'sale_total'


                FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS order_items

                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS reason
                    ON order_items.order_id = reason.post_id

                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS posts
                    ON order_items.order_id = posts.ID

                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS rel ON posts.ID = rel.object_ID
                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} AS tax USING( term_taxonomy_id )
                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->terms} AS term USING( term_id )

                WHERE posts.post_type             = 'shop_order' 
                AND   posts.post_status           = 'publish'

                AND   reason.meta_key            = 'reason_for_purchase'
                AND   term.slug IN ('completed','canceled','failed','processing')
                AND   post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', $start_date ) . "'
                AND   post_date < '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', $end_date ) ) . "'
                GROUP BY reason.meta_value";
```

But when I try to add _order_totals to it, then I can get the totals and number of times each was used, but the meta_value (reason for purchase) no longer displays?
Here is what I have so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM( order_item_meta.meta_value ) AS order_sum,

                count(distinct order_id) AS 'sale_total'


                FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS order_items

                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS order_item_meta
                    ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta.order_item_id

                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS reason
                    ON order_items.order_id = reason.post_id

                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS posts
                    ON order_items.order_id = posts.ID

                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS rel ON posts.ID = rel.object_ID
                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} AS tax USING( term_taxonomy_id )
                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->terms} AS term USING( term_id )

                WHERE posts.post_type             = 'shop_order' 
                AND   posts.post_status           = 'publish'
                AND   order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item'
                AND   order_item_meta.meta_key    = '_line_total'

                AND   reason.meta_key            = 'reason_for_purchase'
                AND   term.slug IN ('completed','canceled','failed','processing')
                AND   post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', $start_date ) . "'
                AND   post_date < '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', $end_date ) ) . "'
                GROUP BY reason.meta_value";
```

All I want to do is show the meta_values, how many times they were used and how much revenue each generated.  It almost works, I can get 2 out of 3 working but can't get all 3 to work and I feel like my problem comes from `SUM( order_item_meta.meta_value ) AS order_sum` but I'm not certain

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Strawberry, I don't follow you.  I mean I understand what you mean by adding a fiddle but you kind of lost me in your comment… I feel like this is a pretty easy question, I just don't know much about querying the database and don't know the best approach to adding the _order_total to my code.. (Sorry for the newbness)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, for anyone else looking --

```
$sql = "SELECT *,
                SUM( order_item_meta.meta_value ) AS order_sum,
                count(distinct order_id) AS 'sale_total'

                FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS order_items

                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS order_item_meta
                    ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta.order_item_id

                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS reason
                    ON order_items.order_id = reason.post_id

                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS posts
                    ON order_items.order_id = posts.ID

                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS rel ON posts.ID = rel.object_ID
                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} AS tax USING( term_taxonomy_id )
                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->terms} AS term USING( term_id )

                WHERE posts.post_type             = 'shop_order' 
                AND   posts.post_status           = 'publish'
                AND   order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item'
                AND   order_item_meta.meta_key    = '_line_total'

                AND   reason.meta_key            = 'reason_for_purchase'
                AND   term.slug IN ('completed','canceled','failed','processing')
                AND   post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', $start_date ) . "'
                AND   post_date < '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', $end_date ) ) . "'
                GROUP BY reason.meta_value";
```

Then to display it I did:

```
 <?php

        foreach($result as $value) {
            $order_total_sum = $value['order_sum'];
            $rounded_total = round($order_total_sum,2);
             ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $value['meta_value']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value['sale_total']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().$rounded_total; ?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php

        }
    ?>
```